# Getting data from unrelated tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this homework for database 'SCHOOL'

- Table Student (StudentID, Name, Surname, etc..)\
- Table Application (ApplicationID, StudentID, ClassID)\
- Table Class (ClassID, ClassName, TeacherID)\
- Table Teacher (TeacherID, Name, Surname, etc..)

There are some other tables and columns in the database but I don't think they're important to this query.

I need to get name of the teachers for whose classes no student signed up. Let's say there is no one signed up for Math class, and I need to get the name of the teacher for that Math class.

```
SELECT Teacher.Name, Teacher.Surname, Class.ClassName
FROM Teacher
INNER JOIN Class ON Class.TeacherID = Teacher.TeacherID
INNER JOIN Application ON Application.ClassID = Class.ClassID
INNER JOIN Student ON Student.StudentID = Application.StudentID
WHERE Application.PredmetID IS NULL
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint - use "where not exists (...)"

Comment: Have a look at `NOT EXISTS` or a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I recommend using table aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.name
from class c join
     teacher t
     on t.teacherid = c.teacherid
where not exists (select 1
                  from application a
                  where a.classid = c.classid
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get name of the teachers for whose classes no student signed up

```
Select T.name
From Teacher T inner join [Class] C on T.TeacherId = C.TeacherId
Where C.ClassId not in (Select Distinct ClassId from Application)
```